# For a non-binary tree what is the optimal database design?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

For a non-binary tree what is the optimal database design ? There is no limit on the depth of the tree.

I know I can go recursive but it is not optimal because I need to query the database many times.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Comment: What is optimal will depend on how you intend to use the data.  Saying you wll do many queries is helpful, but not specific enough.